# Meaning of palm

Tags: meaning, idioms

What is the meaning of Palm and grease in this sentence.

He then listed out the **palms** we had to **grease** in order to open a place to teach kids in our country.

I read this sentence from the book "Revolution 2020".

Answer (score 4):

I think it may refer to the expression :[to  grease the palm or hand](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Grease):

> grease someone's palm or hand, to give someone money as a bribe.

[Example](http://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/grease_someone%27s_palm) : We arrived at Almaty Airport, and from the moment the customs officer made it obvious in his fractured English that our entrance *would be made easier if we greased his palm*, we realised that all our Anglo-Saxon assumptions about how societies are run were not very relevant here.

Comment: Fascinating that the idiom 'To grease (someone's) palm' is from the 1580s.